# Can the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem be applied to show that $|\int_Cf(z)dz|=0$ if $f(z)=csc(z)$ and $C$ is the ellipse $x^2+20(y-\frac{1}4)^2=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem be applied to show that $|\int_Cf(z)dz|=0$ if $f(z)=csc(z)$ and $C$ is the ellipse $x^2+20(y-\frac{1}4)^2=1$? 
 
 I'm pretty sure that I need to find if $csc(z)$ is entire, but I'm not sure how to do that, and I have no idea how the ellipse changes things from the typical $C$ is $|z|=1$ unit circle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\csc$ is not entire: is has a pole at zero. What you need to check is whether there are any poles on or within the ellipse.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, how do I go about checking if there are any poles?

Comment: You could **find** the poles.

Comment: @M.Holder The $\csc$ , being the inverse of the sine, is a function whose poles are easy to find : you just need to find the roots of the sine function. What are the roots of the complex sine? Do you think any of them would lie inside this ellipse?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, the roots of complex sine are 0 and $n\pi$, and only 0 lies in the ellipse (I think), but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @M.Holder The ellipse is a simple closed curve: it would have an inside and outside. If there are no poles within the region, then you can conclude that by Cauchy-Goursat theorem the integral is zero. Otherwise, you must resort to the residue theorem. Looking at the equation, I do not think it contains any poles, therefore, you should be ok.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @M.Holder You are welcome. I request you to answer your own question so that I can upvote it and then we can close it since it is answered.